# Save an image to RAM

Tags: python, image, numpy, sockets, opencv

I want to send an image through socket server. After sending it, I want to show this image on ram (I mean without saving as a file). I made some amazing array changes and finally I reached my original array but I still have an error to show this image. And my array progress is really slow. Is there any suggestion for it and How can I overcome this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ENES\Desktop\python projects\opencvv\opencv_test_1.py", line 44, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("hi",arr2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:155: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'
```

And my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

img= cv2.imread("resim/tfm.jpg")
img1= cv2.imread("resim/tfm.jpg")
print(type(img))
y, x = len(img), len(img[0])
print(y, x)
print(img)
for y1 in range(y):
    i=img[y1]
    print(y1)
    for x1 in range(x):
        data=i[x1]
        imgstr=np.array_str(data)
        #print(img)
        imgstr=imgstr.replace("[","")
        imgstr=imgstr.replace("]","")
        #print(img)
        """
        for a1 in range(3):
            img=i[a1]
            print(img)"""
        imgstr=np.fromstring(imgstr, dtype=int, sep=" ")
        #print(img)
        if x1==0:
            arr1=imgstr
        else:
            arr1=np.vstack((arr1, imgstr))
    if y1==0:
        arr2=arr1
    else:
        arr2=np.vstack((arr2, arr1))
#arr1=np.array(arr1)
print(img.shape, arr2.shape)
#time.sleep(100)
arr2=np.array(arr2.reshape(353,616,3))
print(arr2==img)
print(type(arr2), type(img))
print(img.shape, arr2.shape)

#print(img1)
cv2.imshow("hi",arr2)
```

Comment: Use cv2.imencode to serialize (on sender side) to RAM, then send over socket and cv2.imdecode (on receiver side) to deserialize. You can use 'bmp' as encoding type to save time or 'png' to save space (both types are lossless).

Comment: discard the entire code. do not use strings in any way except for file paths and window names and to tell `imencode()` the file *type* (see prev comment)

Comment: Thank you very much @Micka . I did not know that function exists. I just tried your function, it works fine and faster. And also, I found my mistake I should have declared my datatype. I declared it and my all work (code) executed correctly. However, you know it is too slow using strings and making array progress. As a result, I am going to use this cv2.imencode() function, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem changing only 1 line of code. We need to declare datatype of array. Here is the code:

```
arr2=np.array(arr2.reshape(353,616,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

However, I found a new function cv2.imencode()
This function is exactly what I wanted and it is really faster than my code. So, I am going to use this function.
Thanks to all your answers!

Here is an example of it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

img= cv2.imread("resim/tfm.jpg")

img=cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1]
print(img)
byte_img = img.tobytes()
print(len(byte_img))

recvd_img=np.array(bytearray(byte_img), dtype="uint8")
recvd_img=cv2.imdecode(recvd_img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("sa", recvd_img)
```